# Unique id form field django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-ckeditor

I have a form, which I call inside a nested for loop in my template.

Here's forms.py

```
class SubCategoryItemForm(forms.Form):
    paragraf = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}), required=True, label="Paragraf")
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}), required=True)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}), required=True)
```

views.py

```
def category_view(request, cat_id):
    category = Category.objects.get(id=cat_id)
    context = {"category": category, "sub_category_item_form": SubCategoryItemForm()}
    return render(request, 'registered/category.html', context=context)
```

And in template(without the html):

```
{{ category.name }}
{{ category.description }}
{% for subcat in category.foreign_category.all %}
    {{ subcat.name }}
    {{ subcat.description }}
    <form role="form" id="{{ subcat.id }}" action="{% url 'auth_sub_category_item_add' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ sub_category_item_form }}
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

The issue:
I don't know how I can set the forms field id to be unique. As there might be up to 15 of this form in the sub categories. In specific the description form field needs an unique id. The forms posts and saves, but getting an annoying js error from the CKEditorWidget:

```
Uncaught The editor instance "id_description" is already attached to the provided element.
```

I can suppress this by editing the js, but it would be nice to know if there's any way to set field id dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

It does not actually appear you need to use unique ids in this instance. If you are not gathering the id to use for each form field then you can simply call `auto_id=False` in the form instantiation to ensure no field gets an automated ID attribute added.

For example:

```
def category_view(request, cat_id):
    # note auto_id=False
    form = SubCategoryItemForm(auto_id=False)

    category = Category.objects.get(id=cat_id)
    context = {"category": category, "sub_category_item_form": form}
    return render(request, 'registered/category.html', context=context)
```

This is described in the Django Docs here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.auto_id

Answer (score 1):

You should use a formset which will handle generating unique ids for multiple forms.

Documentation for Django Formset here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#module-django.forms.formsets

Answer (score 1):

Use [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/):

in `forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import formset_factory

SubCategoryItemFormSet = formset_factory(SubCategoryItemForm)
```

in `views.py`:

```
def category_view(request, cat_id):
    category = Category.objects.get(id=cat_id)
    categories_formset = SubCategoryItemFormSet(initial=category.foreign_category.all().values())
    context = {"category": category, "categories_formset": categories_formset}
    return render(request, 'registered/category.html', context=context)
```

in the template:

```
<form role="form" id="{{ category.id }}" action="{% url 'auth_sub_category_item_add' %}" method="POST">
    <table>
        {{ categories_formset }}
    </table>
 </form>
```

Please note that in your `view` you will need to handle the complete `FormSet`, not just one subcategory. Django takes care of mapping each element in the form.

Even better, you can use a [`ModelFormSet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: That's awesome, I got it sorted from your example. Very much appreciated, thumbs up!